# Change tableView section header color

Tags: colors, tableview, sections

I was searching many hours and could not find any solution for, what I thought was simple, but as it seems it is not.
I have a tableView and attached a viewController as subclass of tableViewController.
Now I would just like to change the header color of the sections.
Due to the reason that this is not possible in storyboard, I would really like to know with which code I can make it happen.

Answer (score 3):

this is work 100% and you can change your index or header text color

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // if you have index/header text in your tableview change your index text color 
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *headerIndexText = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    [headerIndexText.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

}
```

Comment: @TomEndres you should mark this as correct as it does what you want :)